# PHP file upload -> replace special chars didn't work

Tags: php, file-upload, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm now searching for a solution for two hours, but nothing I found online helped...

I have a webservice with an upload form, which both work fine. I'm more into JS, my whole service is built in HTML5, CSS3 and JS... but my Upload Form is PHP. I found a script online and it worked, so I was fine. Now I realized, that there is a problem with my service, when I want to upload files with chars like ä,ö,ü and ß. Unfortunately here in Germany these are common chars in our language, so I have to replace them with other chars.

I had a look here and there and at the moment my code looks like this:

```
$files = $_FILES['fileselect'];

foreach ($files['error'] as $id => $err) {
    if ($err == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

        $fn = $files['name'][$id];

        $search_array  = array ('ä', 'ö', 'ü', 'ß');
        $replace_array = array ('ae', 'oe', 'ue', 'ss');

        $gfn = str_replace($search_array, $replace_array, $fn);

        move_uploaded_file(
            $files['tmp_name'][$id],
            'bildtransfer/' . $gfn
        );

        echo "<p>Die Datei $gfn wurde hochgeladen.</p>";
    }
}
```

The upload itself still works with files as long as they don't have those special chars. My file still has all special chars and it seems like there haven't been any replacement?

Do I need preg_replace instead of str_replace? I tried it, but it didn't work either...

I hope you can help me? Would be very pleased!!! :)

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to replace the characters in the file name?

Comment: I suggest you stop them right at the gate and allow for standard characters only `[^a-zA-z0-9]` using an `if` condition.

Comment: Another method you can use is to rename all incoming files with a common starting word, then use the server's timestamp to set a unique number to it and/or `rand()`. Problem solved, and you won't need to worry about non-standard characters. I.e.: `incoming_file_2013_12_09_98372728883011093.xxx`

Comment: George: After uploading the files I put them into a SQL database and list them on the page with AJAX... so when I have chars like äüö or ß in my file name it throws errors :(

Fred: This would be a possible solution, but it would be great to have it renamed... :S

Anyway, thanks for your answers! :)

EDIT: And thanks for the next solution, Fred! ;) I will think about this! :)

Comment: @Fabi You're welcome. That's what I use myself, yet my files are not inserted into a database, just a plain uploaded file residing on server. Cheers (edit: you could make a reference to the file and assign a variable to it before the `move_uploaded_file` function, in order to display the chosen filename from the user's computer) that could work, pretty confident it will.

Comment: I think it would be much better to fix the problem rather than route around it by replacing characters - there's no reason your service should accept some characters and not others! I assume your database uses UTF-8 or Unicode?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the $_FILES array incorrectly. Any error will be stored in `$_FILES['fileselect']['error']` - there's no need for the `foreach` statement.

The original name of the file is stored in `$_FILES['fileselect']['name']`, so try using that in the `str_replace()` call:

```
$file = $_FILES['fileselect'];
if($file['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $fn = $file['name'];

    $search_array  = array ('ä', 'ö', 'ü', 'ß');
    $replace_array = array ('ae', 'oe', 'ue', 'ss');

    $gfn = str_replace($search_array, $replace_array, $fn);

    move_uploaded_file(
        $file['tmp_name'],
        'bildtransfer/' . $gfn
    );

    echo "<p>Die Datei $gfn wurde hochgeladen.</p>";
}
```

To be honest I'm not sure why it works at the moment! Have a read through the PHP documentation on [Handling file uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

To fix the problem so you don't have to bother replacing characters, try telling the browser you're using UTF-8 when you send them, as suggested by @aaron:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Although it does make sense, there could be a problem with the actual filenames themselves. Who knows how the OP's server will react to non-standard characters.

Comment: I'd assume like a normal server would - it wouldn't bat an eye. They're certainly valid file name characters.

Comment: I for one would shy away from using non-standard characters. I'm the "play it safe" kinda guy ;-)

Comment: What interested me is that it *is* safe, to the point where it suggests something's very wrong if it's not working... :/

Answer (score 0):

It could be an encoding issue. Try changing the encoding type to UTF-8 in the headers.